# Jenkins is not recognizing toolchains.xml file

Tags: maven, jenkins

Could you please help me out with the following issue.

I have installed `Jenkins` in my `Windows 7` OS using `Windows Installer`.

- My project has `settings.xml` and `toolchains.xml`, which are placed under `conf` directory of `Maven.Neither`.
- `settings.xml` or `toolchains.xml` files are present under `/usr_home/.m2/` directory.
- I can successfully build project manually , but when tried to build with `Jenkins` , `toolchains.xml` file is not getting identified. I have been receiving error message

> Please make sure you define the required toolchains in your ~/.m2/toochains.xml file.

- I tried putting toolchain.xml file in `/usr_home/.m2/` , but didn't work.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven toolchains.xml location under Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902652/maven-toolchains-xml-location-under-jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I experienced the problem, toolchains.xml were not read from the maven conf library, only settings.xml.

You would have to either place toolchains.xml in you ~/.m2 folder or use
`mvn -t <path>` to point to a secondary toolchains file.

The -t option was not available initially, so you may have to be at mvn 3.2 I think or higher.

Comment: And most probably Jenkins runs as a specific user, so home is probably \users\jenkins or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Niels for the reply. I finally managed to fix the issue. It seems like an existing issue in maven3.3.3 with Jenkins in Window OS where -t option will not work with Jenkins.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28629

So I replaced it with maven3.0.5 and it did the wonder.

Regards,
Jibi